# Database Library/ORM mapper without configuration

Tags: java, python, database, jython

I'm currently planning an application that does work on an object relational database. The work is simple: just fetch data, analyse it, display it to the user and write back some changes. To support a wide range of databases I'm currently searching for access library that meets all (or at least some) of the following requirements (sorted by importance):

- Java or Python. I'm using Jython, so both is possible but I would prefer Python over Java
- Return metadata about the database. I need to be able to fetch a list of all tables and their schema. Ideally, this information is given back as objects.
- ability to fetch a record from multiple tables using a
- complete runtime configuration from code. I don't want something that need i.e. a mapping configuration in some XML file.
- some kind of ORM mapping. I could live without it, but it would be nice to have. I would be totally okay if I get a bunch of objects with data in them and had to do the rest by reflection.

What is the best library for such a task (given that at least one exists ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) which uses [zxJDBC](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) on Jython. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) can also run on Jython, so that's another option. Both let you use Python to declare your models. Django's ORM is a bit less verbose, while SQLAlchemy is arguably more powerful, and tends to offer finer control. There is also a nice declarative wrapper for working with SQLAlchemy called [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki).